# Find $E[X]$ where a coin is flipped 40 times

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be the number of times that a fair coin that is flipped 40 times lands on heads. Find $E[X]$.

**My attempt:**

Intuitively, the mean is $20$. But I also want to find it using the formula.

$\displaystyle E[X]=\sum_{x=0}^{40} xp(x)$

$\displaystyle p(x)=\binom{40}{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{40-x}=\binom{40}{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{40}$

$\displaystyle E[X]=\sum_{x=0}^{40}x\binom{40}{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{40}$

How do I show that this is equal to 20?

Answer (score 4):

Let us prove the following combinatorics equality:

> **Proposition.** For all integers $n\geqslant 1$, one has:
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^nk{n\choose k}=n2^{n-1}.$$

**Proof.** Let define $f\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by:
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}x^k=(1+x)^n.$$
Using the linearity of the derivation, the desired sum is equal to $f'(1)=n(1+1)^{n-1}$. Whence the result. $\Box$

In your case, one has: $\mathbb{E}[X]=20$.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of finding the distribution of the number of heads, you may write $X=\sum_{i}X_i$ where $X_i$ is $1$ with probability $1/2$ and $0$ otherwise.

Now use the linearity of the expectation we get 
\begin{align}
E(X) &= E( \sum_{i}X_i     )            \\
&=\sum_{i}E( X_i     )\\
&=40\cdot 1/2\\
&=20
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
E[X]
&=\sum_{k=0}^{40}\color{#C00}{k\binom{40}{k}}\color{#090}{\left(\frac12\right)^{40}}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{40}\color{#C00}{40\binom{39}{k-1}}\color{#090}{\frac12\left(\frac12\right)^{39}}\\
&=20\left(\frac12\right)^{39}\sum_{k=0}^{40}\binom{39}{k-1}\\
&=20\left(\frac12\right)^{39}2^{39}\\[12pt]
&=20
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to treat each coin toss as a separate Bernoulli outcome and apply the linearity of expectation, rather than computing the expectation on the sum of Bernoulli variables.  Specifically, let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{40}$ be your sample, where $X_i = 1$ if the $i^{\rm th}$ toss is heads, and $X_i = 0$ if the $i^{\rm th}$ toss is tails.  Then if $X = X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_{40}$, we have $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X_1 + \cdots + X_{40}] = \operatorname{E}[X_1] + \operatorname{E}[X_2] + \cdots + \operatorname{E}[X_{40}],$$ and since each $X_i \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p=1/2)$, and its expectation is $$\operatorname{E}[X_i] = p = 1/2,$$ we have $$\operatorname{E}[X] = 40(1/2) = 20.$$

A calculation of the expectation through the binomial distribution is also possible, simply by observing that $$x \binom{40}{x} = \frac{x(40!)}{x! (40-x)!} = \frac{40(39!)}{(x-1)! (39-(x-1))!} = 40 \binom{39}{x-1},$$ for $x = 1, 2, \ldots, 40$, and $0$ if $x = 0$.  Then the sum proceeds as usual, $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \frac{40}{2^{40}} \sum_{x=1}^{40} \binom{39}{x-1} = \frac{40}{2^{40}} \sum_{x=0}^{39} \binom{39}{x} = \frac{40}{2^{40}} 2^{39} = \frac{40}{2} = 20.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
E[X]
&=\frac{1}{2^{40}}\sum_{x=0}^{40}\binom{40}{x}\binom{x}{1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{40}}\sum_{x=0}^{40}\binom{40}{1}\binom{39}{x-1}\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{40}{2^{40}}\sum_{u=0}^{39}\binom{39}{u}\tag{2}\\
&=\frac{40}{2^{40}}\times 2^{39}\tag{3}\\
&=20
\end{align}
$$
where in (1) we used the identity
$$
\binom{n}{m}\binom{m}{k}=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{m-k};\quad n\geq
m \geq k\geq 0$$
in (2) we made a change of variables and in (3) we used the familiar identity
$$
(1+1)^n= \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}.
$$