# Standard deviation of a coin flipped 40 times

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be the number of times that a fair coin that is flipped 40 times lands on heads. Find $SD(X)$ (the standard deviation).

**My attempt:**

Intuitively, $E[X]=20$

$Var(X)=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$ and $SD(X)=\sqrt{Var(X)}$

$\displaystyle E[X^2]=\sum_{x=0}^{40} x^2p(x)=\sum_{x=0}^{40}x^2\binom{40}{x}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{40}$

Is there an easier way of doing this? The answer given in my textbook is $\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: If you know about the binomial distribution you can use its variance formula.

Comment: PS: The answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287039/find-ex-where-a-coin-is-flipped-40-times) gave the method to derive $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk k = 2^{(n-1)}n$, so use similar technique to derive $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk k^2 = 2^{(n - 2)} n (n + 1)$

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: if $Z_i$ is a random variable that is $1$ when the $i$th flip is heads, and zero otherwise, then $X = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$.

Hint 2: If $Z_1,\ldots,Z_n$ are independent, then $$\text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}(Z_i).$$

Comment: The variance of a binomial distribution $B[n,p] = n p (1-p)$, so for $n=40, p = 1/2$, Variance = 10, and $\sigma = \sqrt{10}$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes, and my hints show where the "$np(1-p)$" expression comes from.